# Converting an HTML to a PHP file

Tags: php, html

I designed an order form using pForm. It is an HTML/CSS automated code. But now I think, it should be a PHP file because I need to add PHP code into it.

If I add  just when the HTML file starts and at the end, probably HTML will stop working.

How to change this file to a PHP file and also preserve its present look and feel?

Comment: Have you tried renaming it to php and making sure the internal links are correct?

Comment: I planned that way but I doubt the HTML file header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can literally change the file extension to ".php".

Then you can pepper your new php file with php code like so:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<?php

echo 'Hello world!<br />' ;

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

just change the extension to php

and you can add any PHP code using  tags. this doesnt need to be in the top but in any place of the code :)